# psycopg2.connect() fails when connecting with database

Tags: postgresql, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to access a database via postgresql2 with my jupyter notebook but I receive the following error message.

OperationalError: could not create SSL context: no such file

```py
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

#Connect to postgres
conn_string = "host='xx' sslmode='require' \
               dbname='dbname' port='xx' user='xx' \
               password='xx'"

#Create rework dataset
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
postgreSQL_select_Query = u'SELECT * FROM "xx"."yy"'
conn.set_client_encoding('UNICODE')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
df_imp = cursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_imp, columns=colnames)
```

Expected result is the access to the database and generation of dataframe.
Actual result is OperationalError: could not create SSL context: no such file by step conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-932b2fb01c9f> in <module>
      5 
      6 #Create rework dataset
----> 7 conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
      8 postgreSQL_select_Query = u'SELECT * FROM "xx"."xx"'
      9 conn.set_client_encoding('UNICODE')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    128 
    129     dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 130     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    131     if cursor_factory is not None:
    132         conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory

OperationalError: could not create SSL context: No such process
```

Comment: Can we see the stack trace?

Comment: I have posted it above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several solutions, the problem was the version of psycopg2 library. 
conda update does not install the latest version of the library. However, pip does it and then my code works again!